# Make tabs dynamically except first and last

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have to create tabs, first and last are fixed, and those in between are populated based on the data.

I am stuck and cant figure out how to set the index to my last tab. The code is below:

```
<div ng-click="changeConTab(0)" ng-class="{ 'active-tab': activeConTab == 0 }">Example Tab First</div>

<div ng-click="changeConTab($index + 1)" ng-class="{ 'active-tab': activeConTab == $index + 1}" ng-repeat="contact in someModel.Info">{{ $index + 1 }} Something in between</div>

<div ng-click="changeConTab(???)" ng-class="{ 'active-tab': activeConTab == ??? }">Example Tab Last</div>
```

TS:

```
$scope.activeConTab = 0;
$scope.changeConTab = function (selectedCon) {
    $scope.activeConTab = selectedCon;
}
```

Comment: what about if you assign a fixed big value for the last tab, maybe 999

Comment: @diegoe lol yeah... that does the job, i got fixated on index, thanks bud.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use whatever constant string, such as:

```
<div ng-click="changeConTab('last')" ng-class="{'active-tab': activeConTab == 'last'}">
    Example Tab Last
</div>
```

Using a number is more risky, as it may be used by the elements generated with ng-repeat (well, I guess you won't have 100 tabs, so using `100` may work as well).